# Problems with EditText in android? Cannot perform any actions on it without crashing

Tags: android

I'm very new to android programming, and somewhat inexperienced with Java itself. I'm having a  problem, as described by the title. I'm trying to change some text in the Main Activity within   the program but whatever i do, the app crashes on startup, and a NullPointerException is thrown. Here is the XML code for the EditText field, in fragment_main.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"
    android:hint="@string/hinty"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

And here is the code in MainActivity.java, in the onCreate() method, after the other stuff in there:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text.getText();
```

Finally, here is the error log:

```
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-27 13:23:29.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23317):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
```

I'm running Jelly Bean 4.2.2 on the device I'm testing this on. So, can anyone help?

Comment: Please, post the **full** stack trace, and also your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: inside onCreate() you are inflating(setting content) of fragment_main.xml, right?

Answer (score 0):

Add line in your onCreate method:

> setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text.getText();
}
```

I get NullPointerAssignment commenting the "SetContentView" line, so I guess this is your problem.